# Server Manager Running on Windows 10 getting WinRM Error

Tags: windows, windows-10, winrm

I have Server Manager installed on my Win 10 (not anniversary ed) workstation to help manage our Win 2012R2 servers.  When I try and run a DNS BPA on our 4 DNS servers, I get the error message "Server Manager could not start the task due to the following error: Failed to open the runspace pool. The Server Manager WinRM plug-in might be missing or corrupted."  I don't see any other event log messages on my machine or on the servers.

Comment: What happens if you patch windows up to the latest version?

Comment: I am trying to do that but unfortunately Anniversary edition won't install.  I'm working with MS on that issue already.  Maybe the two are related.